# Unable to open the file downloaded using "js-file-download" library

Tags: javascript, file

I'm using the `js-file-download` in my react project to download files by using the following code.

```
var fileDownload = require('js-file-download');
fileDownload(data, 'filename.pdf');
```

I have provided the correct path for `data` and the file is downloading. When I open the downloaded file it shows an error `Failed to load PDF document.` File path given in `data` shows the correct pdf document in browser. Something has corrupted during my download I think. Anybody have any idea?

Comment: File that you downloaded with `fileDownload` and your original file have same size/identical? Try to open pdf file with notepad after download

Comment: When I opened the file in notepad it gives the file path as content. I think that was the reason. So how should I give the file, as file path or binary data or any other mode?

Answer (score 3):

The `data` parameter is not for specifying a path, it is for providing the actual data in the file.

Example:

```
const fileDownload = require('js-file-download');
fileDownload('first name;last name\nJohn;Doe\nJane;Doe', 'filename.csv');
```

So if you want to provide a PDF file for downloading, you'll have to figure to a way to store the contents of your PDF in the data variable.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, that's what I had to do:

```js
// from js-file-download docs
import Axios from axios;
import fileDownload from 'js-file-download';

function download(url: string, filename: string) {
  Axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'blob',
  }).then(res => {
    fileDownload(res.data, filename);
  });
}
```

Passing blob to `fileDownload` helped